# Pyodbc python reading uncommitted data in SQL stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using Python v 3.7.5 and pyodbc v 4.0.30 (I did test the below on v 4.0.26 as well, but got the same results). SQL Server is 2016 on the latest SP and CU.

I am calling a stored procedure from Python using Pyodbc. The stored procedure does some inserts, then selects the inserted data to insert into another table. Finally, it runs a SELECT statement on that table to return the data.

The problem is, sometimes data is returned, and sometimes not. It is sporadic and there is no pattern to it. It almost seems like pyodbc runs the stored proc then immediately runs the SELECT, whether the data is committed or not.

I did remove all the "with (nolock)" statements, added BEGIN/END around each statement etc to try and find a possible solution, but nothing seems to work. My isolation level is the default READ_COMMITTED. I even forced it in the stored proc, but of course, no luck.

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
    IF @incoming_outgoing = 'incoming'
BEGIN
    --This is the raw audit of the webhook that Twilio calls
    INSERT INTO tbl_django_actions_audit_incoming_whatsapp_message
    VALUES( @sms_message_sid,
            @num_media,
            @sms_sid,
            @sms_status,
            @sms_body,
            @to_number,
            @num_segments,
            @message_sid,
            @account_sid,
            @from_number,
            @api_version,
            @date_time_requested
            )


    DECLARE @count_session INT
    SET @count_session = 0

    DECLARE @hash_to_return varchar(100)
    SET @hash_to_return = @the_hash_for_session


    --Lets check if this conversation has a valid session within the last 24 hours
    --Count should always be 1 or 0. It should never be more than 1
    SELECT @count_session = COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_main] with (nolock)
    WHERE from_number = @from_number
        AND to_number = @to_number
    AND convert(datetime2, date_time_requested) between dateadd(hour, -24, convert(datetime2,getdate())) AND convert(datetime2, getdate())


    IF @count_session = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_main]
        VALUES (
            @from_number,
            @to_number,
            @date_time_requested,
            @hash_to_return
        )

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_conversation]
        VALUES (
            @hash_to_return,
            @sms_body,
            @incoming_outgoing,
            @date_time_requested
        )


    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        --Lets get that session hash. Only 1 record must be returned. ALWAYS. But we add the TOP just in case.
        SELECT TOP 1 @hash_to_return = session_hash
        FROM [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_main] with (nolock)
        WHERE from_number = @from_number
        AND to_number = @to_number
        AND convert(datetime2, date_time_requested) between dateadd(hour, -24, convert(datetime2,getdate())) AND convert(datetime2, getdate())

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_conversation]
        VALUES (
            @hash_to_return, --We're using @hash_to_return from above
            @sms_body,
            @incoming_outgoing,
            @date_time_requested
        )
    END

    ---XXXX Here is sometimes returns data, and sometimes not XXXX ----
    SELECT  a.session_hash,
        a.sms_body,
        a.incoming_outgoing
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_django_message_whatsapp_session_conversation] a with (nolock)
    WHERE a.session_hash = @hash_to_return
    --AND a.incoming_outgoing = 'outgoing'
    AND convert(datetime2, a.date_time_requested) between dateadd(hour, -24, convert(datetime2,getdate())) AND convert(datetime2, getdate())
    ORDER BY a.date_time_requested DESC -- The ORDER BY is super important for our logic in Django


END
```

My only solution was to move the SELECT statement to another stored procedure, and add a time.sleep(2) between the stored proc above, and the one that reads the data. (I did find that adding a WAITFOR DELAY before the final SELECT has the same effect).

[Sometimes data is returned and sometimes not. It is very sporadic with no pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Pz0.jpg)

Comment: Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the very first executable statement in your stored procedure?

Comment: Hi Gord. Yes, I do. I tried with and without it, but getting the same results.